# Text field validation in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have a text field that need to accept numeric input only.
I have tried validating it with RegEx and it works pretty well but if I try to copy-paste alpha-numeric input, then it breaks and cannot handle it.

My input:

```
<input className="form-control form-control-md"  value={number} onChange={(e)=>{setNumber(e.target.value)
validateNumber(e.target.value)}} type="text" name="number"  placeholder="Please insert a number"/>

function validateNumber(e)
{
    const reInt = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    const LimitInt = /^([0-9]{9})$/;
    if(!reInt.test(e) && !LimitInt.test(e))
    {
        setNumber(e.substring(0,e.length-1));
    }
    if(e.length>9){
        setNumber("");
    }
}
```

Now this sample code does the job and doesn't allow to insert characters other than numeric ones, (it also prevents adding more than 9 numbers).

How can I make it handle even the copy-pasted strings ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the type of element like type="number". ?

Comment: It makes sense to set the type="number", something I missed. But still doesn't work. And even after setting it to "number" it still accepts letters, somehow it ignored the `ValidateNumber` function and the RegEx inside of it...

Comment: type="number" should work, it should extract the numbers from alpha numeric characters , try - <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" />